# Getting Empty Array on postman when using Mongooes with Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to post data in my MongoAtlas using Mongoose on Express and NodeJS. But Postman is returning a empty array. What I'm doing wrong

**Database:** mongodb+srv://*username*:*password*@*clusterName*.8xpcg.mongodb.net/*databaseName*?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Here are the Files
**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('dotenv/config');
server.use(bodyParser.json());
//Importing Routes
const mcqRoutes = require('./routes/mcq');
const { application } = require('express');

//Routes
server.use('/mcq', mcqRoutes);

//DB Connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<clusterName>.8xpcg.mongodb.net/<databaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority', ()=>
    console.log('DB Connected')
)

//Server Listening Port
server.listen(6969);
```

**MCQ Route File**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mcq = require('../models/mcq');

router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.send('We are on MCQS Homepage');
})

router.post('/', async (req, res)=> {
    const Mcq = new mcq ({
        "_id": req.body._id,
        "m_title": req.body.m_title,
        "m_slug": req.body.m_slug,
        "m_question": req.body.m_question,
        "m_alternatives": req.body.m_alternatives,
        "m_number": req.body.m_number,
        "m_subject": req.body.m_subject,
        "m_language": req.body.m_language
    });
    try {
        const saveMcq = await mcq.save();
        res.json(saveMcq);
    } catch(err){
        res.json({ message: err});
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

**MCQ Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const McqScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {type: Number, require: true},
    m_date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    m_title: {type: String, require: true},
    m_slug: {type: String, require: true},
    m_question: {type: String, require: true},
    m_alternatives: {type: Array, require: true},
    m_number: {type: String},
    m_class: {type: String},
    m_subject: {type: String},
    m_type: {type: String},
    m_board: {type: String},
    m_paper: {type: String},
    m_unit: {type: String},
    m_language: {type: String},

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('mcq', McqScheme);
```

PostMan Response
[image: PostMan Response | Getting Empty Array on postman when using Mongooes with Node JS]

Comment: If the response is an object with property `message`, then your error handler must be being called. It's possible that `err` is not being turned into a string properly by `res.json`. Try `console.log(err.message)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(err))` or placing some breakpoints in a debugger if you can and inspecting values when it is triggered.

Comment: It was a Case Error.
Now I'm getting 'Operation `mcqs.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms'

Comment: Well I suppose that's something else to google, I get results about database connection issues. That's all I can help with right now.

Comment: Alright Thanks Man

Answer (score 0):

1. In MCQ Router File Try Block has `mcq.save();` in wrong Case.
2. After that I got `buffering timed out after 10000ms` Error. In Server.js File I add code in mongoose.connect. `mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECTION, {   useNewUrlParser: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true}) .then(() => console.log("Database connected!")) .catch(err => console.log(err));` and also update my IP Address in MongoAtlas